# Reindex/shaping Dask DataArray

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I want to apply some metric (e.g. RMSE) to a model ensemble with different forecast/initialization times (see example below).

```
ds_mod = <xarray.DataArray (ensemble: 12, init_time: 120, fore_time_i: 12, nj: 304,     ni: 448)>
dask.array<shape=(12, 120, 12, 304, 448), dtype=float64, chunksize=(12, 12, 12, 304, 448)>
Coordinates:
    lon          (nj, ni) float64 168.3 168.4 168.5 168.7 168.8 168.9 169.0 ...
    lat          (nj, ni) float64 31.1 31.25 31.4 31.55 31.69 31.84 31.99 ...
  * ensemble     (ensemble) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  * fore_time_i  (fore_time_i) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
  * init_time    (init_time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 ...
    fore_time    (init_time, fore_time_i) datetime64[ns] dask.array<shape=(120, 12), chunksize=(12, 12)>
```

Dimensions without coordinates: nj, ni

My issue is I have the observations with dims like this:

```
ds_obs = <xarray.DataArray 'sic' (time: 131, nj: 304, ni: 448)>
dask.array<shape=(131, 304, 448), dtype=float64, chunksize=(1, 304, 448)>
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-02-01 2000-03-01 ...
Dimensions without coordinates: nj, ni
```

My idea was to reformat the observations to look like the model like this (sort of a brute force approach):

```
def format_obs_like_model(ds_mod, ds_obs):
    ''' Reformats observational dataset to be structured like a model forecast dataset 
    Format obs like model (i.e. ensemble x init_time x forecast_time) '''

    ds_obs_X = (ds_mod.copy() * np.nan).load() # Have to call load here to assign ie below
    for (i, e) in enumerate(ds_obs_X.ensemble):
        for (j, it) in enumerate(ds_obs_X.init_time):
            ds_obs_X[i, j, :] = ds_obs.sel(time=ds_mod.fore_time.sel(init_time=it))
    return ds_obs_X
```

This works if data is within system memory but fails outside, because I am explicitly load()'ing to allow assignment.

Is there a better way to do this reformatting? (That will work with OOM data)

I have originally tried `reindex_like()`:

```
ds_obs_X = ds_obs.reindex_like(ds_mod)
```

But because ds_mod has two differently named time dimensions (for initialization time and forecast time), I couldn't get it to work.